# How to emit event from swift view to react native app

Tags: react-native

I have written custom UIView with UIButton in Swift and bridged it to react native app. The view is shown correctly. Now I want to emit event on button click to react native javascript side. How can I achieve that?

--Edit--

I can't emit event, because `var bridge: RCTBridge!` is always null.

Answer (score 0):

f you add your Swift file to your app through the Xcode File>New File menu option. You will need to import `RCTBridgeModule.h` in this header file.

```
// CalendarManager-Bridging-Header.h
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
```

If you look at facebooks example it is pretty straight forward.

```
    //create your class
@objc(CalendarManager)
    class CalendarManager: NSObject {

      @objc func addEvent(name: String, location: String, date: NSNumber) -> Void {
        // Date is ready to use!
      }

    }
```

@objc is used to make sure everything is exported properly at runtime

Then create a separate .m file with objective c code, you have to mix the two. Remember swift does not support macros. To export it you simply wrap the function in an  `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` macro and you can easily use the event dispatcher

```
// CalendarManagerBridge.m
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CalendarManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(addEvent:(NSString *)name location:(NSString *)location date:(nonnull NSNumber *)date)
//throw in the event dispatcher if you want
@end
```

Take a look at these links, it will walk you through the process

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content

https://colinramsay.co.uk/2015/07/04/react-native-eventemitters.html

Comment: In my case I had to pass bridge from view manager to UIView class.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem, below is how I resolved the problem.

The [Official document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content) is a little bit different from our implementation, it just defines a `ViewManager` to expose the methods and variables to `js`, but we defined a `ViewManager` to return a `UIView`, and we want to return methods and variables from this `UIView`.

The `RCTBridge *bridge` bridge is included inRCTViewManager, but remember our `ViewManager` inherits the `RCTViewManager` class, so we can still access the `bridge`, we can pass the `bridge` from `ViewManager` to the `UIView`.

Below is how we can do to access the `bridge`:

`CustomUIButtonViewManager.swift`

```
import Foundation
@objc(CustomUIButtonViewManager)
class CustomUIButtonViewManager : RCTViewManager {
  var customButtonView:CustomButtonView!
  override func view() -> UIView! {
    customButtonView = CustomButtonView(bridge: self.bridge)
    return customButtonView
  }
}
```

and for our `CustomButtonView.swift`, define it like below:

```
import UIKit
class CustomButtonView: UIView {
  var bridge: RCTBridge!
  init(bridge: RCTBridge!) {
    this.bridge = bridge
    //So you have saved the bridge in this View
  }
```

Now you can access the `bridge` variable in this UIView. 
This is how I resolve this problem, hope that can be helpful for you.